# Display Preferences Bug?

Tags: issues

we just tried to edit some of the display preferences (unticking various things we don't need) but upon clicking 'save' the changes do not hold, even though the green message box says "changes saved".

Is this a known bug? Is anyone having the same issue or know a solution?

Comment: You might a specific example and the version of your install to your question.

Comment: And confirm if same is on demo. and check you aren't flipping between http and https or www and no-www

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to increase php variable `post_max_size` in `php.ini` or using php function `ini_set()`.